# CSR with DN values from config file and command line

Tags: configuration, openssl

I have the following section in my openssl configuration:

```
[ req_distinguished_name ]
  countryName                     = Country Name (2 letter code)
  stateOrProvinceName             = State or Province Name
  localityName                    = Locality Name
  0.organizationName              = Organization Name
  organizationalUnitName          = Organizational Unit Name
  commonName                      = Common Name
  emailAddress                    = Email Address
  countryName_default             = DE
  stateOrProvinceName_default     = myState
  localityName_default            = myLocality
```

On the command line I am creating a new CSR with the following command:

```
openssl req -config /home/loci/tmp/certs/openssl.conf -new -batch -sha256 -verbose -key ServerCert.key -passin env:password -out ServerCert.csr
```

When I'm adding '-subj "/CN=ServerCA"' the predefined values from the configuration file are ignored.
I know the values are asked for in interactive mode. But I have to use batch mode because the final script has to run automated. Setting the complete string on the command line would be the alternate option but I'd like to move as much configuration to the config file as possible.

Is there a possibility to only define parts of the DN on the command line?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: You should also state the shell you are using because they are different. Bash has the [Here Documents](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) so that you can build the entire config in a script and send it into the command.

Comment: @jww: it is about programming because topic is to create a script to automatically create certificates with some parts of the DN predefined in openssl.cnf
The type of shell is not relevant as the openssl commands are the same everywhere. But yes: bash is the default shell. Question was how to define parts of the DN in openssl.cnf and parts on the command line.